# PostgreSql Pasar un array de strings como argumento a una función

Tags: postgresql

Estoy creando una función que recibe dos arreglos uno de enteros y uno de strings y crea vistas materializadas, asignando como nombre una concatenación de estos parámetros. De esta manera:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reports_mt_views(
    accounts integer[],
    namesa text[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   i integer;       
BEGIN        
FOREACH i IN ARRAY accounts
    LOOP 
    EXECUTE 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW pps.order_reports_materialized_' || accounts[i] || '_' || namesa[i] || ' AS
...
```

Sin embargo cuando lanzo la función de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT reports_mt_views(ARRAY [1,9,504231,505674], '{''a'',''b'',''c'',''d''}');
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'a'"
LINE 1: ...TE MATERIALIZED VIEW pps.order_reports_materialized_1_'a'
```

Que ocurre por las comillas simples que le estoy enviando. De otra manera no logro enviar el array de strings, si lo hago así:

```
SELECT reports_mt_views(ARRAY [1,9,504231,505674], {'a','b','c','d'}, 3);

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: ...T pps.reports_mt_views(ARRAY [1,9,504231,505674], {'a','b','...
                                                               ^
```

No logro enviar y leer el arreglo de *strings* para generar el nombre de la vista materializada.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente, en vez de nombrar el parametro, define solo el tipo y usa un alias para $1, $2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reports_mt_views(
    integer[],
    text[])
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   accounts ALIAS FOR $1;
   namesa alias FOR $2;
   i integer;       
BEGIN        
FOREACH i IN ARRAY accounts
    LOOP 
    EXECUTE 'CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW pps.order_reports_materialized_' || accounts[i] || '_' || namesa[i] || ' AS
...
```